# Command Prompt cant open file in Python26\Scripts

Tags: python, windows

This seems to be a common problem, but I cant seem to fin a solution that works. My PATH is set with C:\Python26\Scripts;C:\Python26\Lib and PYTHONPATH is similarly set. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

> python CellProfiler.py --help
>
> python: cant open file 'CellProfiler.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

Comment: What's your input and output?

Comment: Could python \absolute\path\to\CellProfiler.py --help work?

Comment: are you running it from c:\python26\scripts? otherwise it won't work. You're not yet running this script from python - you pass shell variables. Constructs like `sys.oscwd()` (get current working dir) may help inside scripts, but here not python, but shell is responsible

Comment: I thought the PATH variables make the scripts accessible in the command prompt?

Comment: @heinrich5991 you have the answer... though I'm still not sure why I cant run it from python. Apparently the commandprompt is ok with running it as an executable.

Comment: @Cenoc I provided the answer as comment because I wasn't sure if it works and I couldn't test because I moved to linux (deleted the comment and added it as answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `CellProfiler.py --help` directly from the command line.

This will work, if you've installed Python via the installer, which registers the .py file extension as executable, and therefore Windows searches in `PATH` if you try to execute one.